# Insert select changes table with max id of other table with transactions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a changes table and I need to assign the next available id for which the id's are in the transactions table. After the batch is complete it will be posted to the transactions table. How do I get the max + 1 of the other table in the select insert statement? And I have to concatenate it to the code_id in the same query.

```
INSERT INTO CHANGES 
(P.CODE, P.ID, P.CODE_ID, P.FIRST_NAME, P.MIDDLE_NAME, P.LAST_NAME) 
SELECT 'P', MAX(transactionstable.ID) +1, 
'P0000' + MAX(transactionstable.ID) +1, 'first','middle','last';
```

Comment: Why not use an `identity` column instead?

Comment: `SELECT 'P', (SELECT max(id) + 1 FROM transactiontable), 'P0000' + (SELECT max(id) + 1 FROM transactiontable), 'first', ...`

Comment: Why do you need to generate the ID in the Changes tables. Why not let an identity column in the transactions table suffice. You are always at risk that you create an ID in the changes table that is a duplicate of an ID in the transaction table if any other inserts have taken place in the transactions table.

Comment: Why two columns with essentially the same data? ID and CODE_ID are the same thing.

Comment: It is a erp database i'm synchronizing with a crm. So I don't have access to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO CHANGES (
                         P.CODE, 
                         P.ID, 
                         P.CODE_ID,
                         P.FIRST_NAME,
                         P.MIDDLE_NAME, 
                         P.LAST_NAME
                         ) 
    SELECT  P,      --remove single quote, otherwise it is static value
            MAX(transactionstable.ID) +1, 
           'P0000' + CAST((MAX(transactionstable.ID) +1) as VARCHAR(50)), --Conversion here for string concatenation 
            first,  --remove single quote, otherwise it is static value
            middle, --remove single quote, otherwise it is static value
            last    --remove single quote, otherwise it is static value

/*********************
    missing here
**********************/    
    FROM transactions
```